# Error: Could not find or load main class Start (Minecraft Coding)

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently coding my **Minecraft** *Client*. I am getting an error stating

> AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed

Here is my code.

```
package me.nathan.retired;

import org.lwjgl.util.Display;

public class Retired {

    public static String Client_Name = "Retired";
    public static double Client_Version = 1.0;

    public static final Retired Retired = new Retired();

    public static void StartClient(){
        Display.setTitle(Client_Name + "(rel" + Client_Version + ")");
    }


}
```

The `setTitle` is getting highlighted as well. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I forgot to say that I get the AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed when running minecraft through Eclipse.

Comment: `AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed` is (somewhat) normal when Minecraft crashes or doesn't load properly.  It just means that the game exited without properly closing the audio engine, and the engine is closing itself.  Most likely, your workspace is missing some of its libraries (if it can't find `Start`, some parts of MCP are missing at least at runtime).